# Convert object to right type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, interface

I have little problem. 
In first method of my code I've loaded data about students from txt file to List collection. There are more types of students (classes PrimaryStudent, SecondaryStudent, HightSchoolStudent, UniversityStudent, ExternStudent etc...)
Now, in other method I want to save every kind of student to different directory. My problem is in that I have all objects in one collection in that interface. How can now I differentiate or what should I do to differentiate all types of students? Please help.

Comment: Are you using a generic List<Student> ?

Comment: Down is solution whitch was I looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is generic, i.e. `List<Student>` you could do the following:

```
List<PrimaryStudent> primaryStudents = myStudentList.OfType<PrimaryStudent>().ToList();
```

If your list is not generic, you can separate them like so:

```
foreach(var s in myStudentList)
{
  if(s is PrimaryStudent)
  { 

    // add to PrimaryStudents list
  }
  else if(s is SecondaryStudent)
  {

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: OfType does not work if you want to store regular students as well because OfType<Student> will return not only Students but also Primary and SecondaryStudents. The OfType LINQ operator does also share the same issue. Have a look at my solution below how this can be done in a safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`is` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in c#.

Example:

```
List<IStudent> students = new List<IStudent>();

students.Add(new PrimaryStudent());
students.Add(new SecondaryStudent());
students.Add(new HightSchoolStudent());

foreach (IStudent student in students)
{
    if (student is PrimaryStudent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This was a PrimaryStudent");
    }
    else if (student is SecondaryStudent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This was a SecondaryStudent");
    }
    else if (student is HightSchoolStudent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This was a HightSchoolStudent");
    }
}

Console.Read();
```

Output:

```
This was a PrimaryStudent
This was a SecondaryStudent
This was a HightSchoolStudent
```

Comment: The is keyword does only work if you never want to store regular Students which is the base class for primary and secondary students.

Comment: It would work if you put the if statement below all other if statements.

Comment: That is true but this code would be hard to maintain and extend. I do not want to write extra code for a new student type every time. My generic solution does not need to know which student types exist. It does simply group them by type.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get from the collection all student types and then save them by type to their final location. The solution presented here does not make use of the is or the OfType<> LINQ method since these operators do fail to work correctly if you want to store Students, PrimaryStudents and SecondaryStudents in differnt folders.

In other words if you want to treat instances of your base class differntly (e.g. save to a differnt folder) you need to abandon OfType and the is operator but check the type directly.

```
class Student { }
class PrimaryStudent : Student { }
class SecondaryStudent : Student { }

private void Run()
{
    var students = new List<Student> { new PrimaryStudent(), new PrimaryStudent(), new SecondaryStudent(), new Student() };
    Save(@"C:\University", students);
}

private void Save(string basePath, List<Student> students)
{
    foreach (var groupByType in students.ToLookup(s=>s.GetType()))
    {
        var studentsOfType = groupByType.Key;
        string path = Path.Combine(basePath, studentsOfType.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Saving {0} students of type {1} to {2}", groupByType.Count(), studentsOfType.Name, path);
    }

}

Saving 2 students of type PrimaryStudent to C:\University\PrimaryStudent
Saving 1 students of type SecondaryStudent to C:\University\SecondaryStudent
Saving 1 students of type Student to C:\University\Student
```